# Separate in Google Sheets with regex formula two repeated sentences in same cell without space

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I have many cells in google sheets with different duplicate sentence or phrases per cell, merged without space.
I've tried to separate them with regex at no avail. These are just two examples of many cells, some are uppercase others lower case, or combined, there is no clear pattern except the repetition)

**Example Cell A1:**

> "programs january 2000-Intel-Intelprograms january 2000-Intel-Intel"

**Desired Result Cell B1:**

> "Programs January 2000-Intel-Intel"

**Example Cell A2:**

> "Sesions for 1996 for MARCHSesions for 1996 for MARCH"

**Desired Result Cell B2:**

> "Sesions for 1996 for MARCH"

**Formula Intents **

```
1rsts Regex I've tried: "(?s)\b((?i)[áéíóúñü\w\s\W0-9]+?)\B\1"
Result: I thing Google Sheets REGEX cannot use the "\1" to detect duplicates, but this formula worked in: https://regex101.com/ and http://regexstorm.net/tester

2nd Regex I'm trying is something like this, but cannot get it right:
"regexreplace(A1,"(^[A-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ\w0-9]+[A-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ\w0-9]+)\b|([A-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ\w0-9]+\B[A-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ\w0-9]+)","$1")
```

Comment: Google Sheets `REGEX` formulas use RE2, and it does not support backreferences.

Comment: If the sentence is exactly the same, why not just cut it in half? I don't think you need regex at all.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; ".{"&LEN(A1:A)/2&"}"))
```

[image]